# How to determine the type of an object and pass it as an argument to a method?

Tags: c#, oop

My application contains one base class called `Statistic` and three classes which inherit from it: `LSP`, `CPU`, `Memory`. I also have an additional class called `ExecuteRequest` whose constructor takes either an instance of `Statistic` or one of the more derived types (`LSP`, `CPU` or `Memory`). What I want to do is: determine what type of object it is (whether `LSP`, `CPU` or `Memory`).

To accomplish this, I created the `DeterminateKpiType` method which would check the incoming `Statistic` instance and cast it to a specific property of that type.  Once complete, this specific object will be passed to the `RunRequest()` method.  Unfortunately I encountered a problem while attempting to solve this.

I received errors (when invoking `DeterminateKpiType()`) saying that it cannot return those types and I have no clue how to pass the object to the `RunRequest()` method. How can I achieve this result? If something is unclear feel free to revert/ask.

Here is the code listing:

```
class ExecuteRequest
{
    public Statistic KPI { get; set; }
    public LSP LSP { get; set; }
    public CPU CPU { get; set; }
    public Memory Memory { get; set; }

    public ExecuteRequest(Statistic kpi)
    {
        KPI = kpi;
        specificStatisticKPI = DeterminateKpiType(KPI);
        RunRequest(specificStatisticKPI)
    }

    public T DeterminateKpiType<T>(Statistic KPI)
    {
        if (KPI.GetType() == typeof(LSP))
        {
            LSP = KPI as LSP;
            return LSP;
        }

        if (KPI.GetType() == typeof(CPU))
        {
            CPU = KPI as CPU;
            return CPU;
        }

        if (KPI.GetType() == typeof(Memory))
        {
            Memory = KPI as Memory;
            return Memory;
        }

    }

    public void RunRequest(specificStatisticKPI what type ?????)
    {
        specificStatisticKPI.SomeMethod
    }
}
```

Comment: could you include the real method signature(s) for `RunRequest`?  And where is the `specificStatisticKPI` defined?

Comment: most all of my inherited clas has the same methods with diffrent implementation so after i would be able to pass it through RunRequest i would just use : specificStatisticKPI.SomeMethod.

Comment: `public void RunRequest(specificStatisticKPI )` missing the input parameter type.

Comment: yes because i dont know how to pass it :) and DeterminateKPIType - the returns are bad implemented. SO i got problems in those two places.

Comment: Your code makes no sense as it is.  That's simply not how generics work.  Is that `SomeMethod` method that you're calling in `RunRequest` a member of the common base class or will it be different for each derived type?

Comment: SomeMethod (s) are implemented inside base class (Statistic) and all of inherited classes using that once or there are some more methods inside base class which are ovveriden by inherited classes.

Comment: i just want to determinate commin type and then pass it to some method inside that class is it really not possible?

Answer (score 0):

i have a few theories i dont if it would help but i would love to tell you, first `specificStatisticKPI` what type is it? if its set to be `Statistic` type i think you need to convert it or it cant contain `Memory` , `LSP` or `CPU`, that is one secondly the `RunRequest()` method should be able to take three types of classes or the classes can be converted to each other implicitly if these things are handled i believe you code should work . 
best of luck

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of challenges with the approach you're taking (and I suspect that these are causing some of the confusion you're facing) so I will try to outline these and offer solutions that should give you the results you are seeking.

### Challenge 1:

You're doing way too much logic in the constructor of your `ExecuteRequest` class.  Constructors should be limited to EXTREMELY simple conditional checks (if any) and should most certainly not perform any operations.  Here you would have at least two options:

1. Refactor your `ExecuteRequest` class to be a static class with no constructor (I don't see a reason based on your current code to have it be an instantiatable type) and a static method that accepts a `Statistic` instance as an argument (your `RunRequest` method for example).
2. Change the constructor to only initialize the `Statistic` instance and make the code that consumes `ExecuteRequest` makes the call to RunRequest.

Of particular note on constructors (taken from MSDN links below):

> ...The use of public fields is not a recommended programming practice
>   because it allows any method anywhere in a program unrestricted and
>   unverified access to an object's inner workings. Data members should
>   generally be private, and should be accessed only through class
>   methods and properties.

and

> Do minimal work in the constructor. Constructors should not do much
>   work other than to capture the constructor parameters. The cost of any
>   other processing should be delayed until required.

Here are some helpful guidelines for constructors and how best to use them:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060(v=vs.100).aspx

### Challenge 2:

Using generics and conditional type logic are *usually* mutually exclusive (where one option is favored over the other) and combining the two is often a [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).  When using generics one of the benefits come from the use of 'generic type constraints'.  These constraints allow you to know as much as possible about all potential incoming implementations of a base type while allowing new instances to be created without having to modify the code.  The idea is essentially one of [Liskov Substitution](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LSP.aspx).

For more information on generic type constraints, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Here is an excerpt from the MSDN documentation:

> By constraining the type parameter, you increase the number of
>   allowable operations and method calls to those supported by the
>   constraining type and all types in its inheritance hierarchy.
>   Therefore, when you design generic classes or methods, if you will be
>   performing any operation on the generic members beyond simple
>   assignment or calling any methods not supported by System.Object, you
>   will have to apply constraints to the type parameter.

---

### Possible Solutions

There are always many ways to solve a programming problem like this, here are two variations that should address the challenges you are facing.

**Note:**  I created these in LinqPad so they are all tested to work (but your actual classes may differ from mine).

### Variation 1 (Instantiatable `ExecuteRequest` with a class-wide generic type constraint):

```
void Main() {
    LSP lspStatistic = new LSP();
    Memory memoryStatistic = new Memory();
    CPU cpuStatistic = new CPU();

    ExecuteRequest<CPU> cpuRequest = new ExecuteRequest<CPU>(cpuStatistic);
    ExecuteRequest<LSP> lspRequest = new ExecuteRequest<LSP>(lspStatistic);
    ExecuteRequest<Memory> memoryRequest = new ExecuteRequest<Memory>(memoryStatistic);

    cpuRequest.RunRequest();
    lspRequest.RunRequest();
    memoryRequest.RunRequest();
}

public class ExecuteRequest<TStatistic> where TStatistic : Statistic {

    private TStatistic _kpi; //Whichever type the class was created as.  This enables us to have intellisense support for the specific generic type outside of this class if we need it.

    //Hide the default constructor from the outside world (require a statistic)
    private ExecuteRequest() : this(null) {

    } // end default constructor

    public ExecuteRequest(TStatistic kpi) {
        _kpi = kpi;
    } // end overloaded constructor

    public void RunRequest() {
        this.KPI.SomeMethod(); //Since we know that KPI will be AT LEAST a Statistic as specified by the generic type constraint, we can access the base class members here without having to figure out which type it is because we don't actually care what type it is, just that it is a Statistic
    } // end method RunRequest

    public TStatistic KPI {
        get {
            return _kpi;
        } set {
            _kpi = value;
        }
    } // end property KPI

} // end class ExecuteRequest

public abstract class Statistic {

    protected Statistic() {

    } // end default constructor

    public abstract void SomeMethod();

} // end class Statistic

public class LSP : Statistic {

    public LSP() : base() {

    } // end default constructor

    public override void SomeMethod() {
        Debug.WriteLine("This is the LSP implementation of SomeMethod.");
    } // end method SomeMethod

} // end class LSP

public class CPU : Statistic {

    public CPU() : base() {

    } // end default constructor

    public override void SomeMethod() {
        Debug.WriteLine("This is the CPU implementation of SomeMethod.");
    } // end method SomeMethod

} // end class CPU

public class Memory : Statistic {

    public Memory() : base() {

    } // end default constructor

    public override void SomeMethod() {
        Debug.WriteLine("This is the Memory implementation of SomeMethod.");
    } // end method SomeMethod

} // end class Memory
```

**Outputs:**

> This is the CPU implementation of SomeMethod.
>
> This is the LSP implementation of SomeMethod.
>
> This is the Memory implementation of SomeMethod.

### Variation 2 (Static `ExecuteRequest` with a generic type argument and constraint):

```
void Main() {
    LSP lspStatistic = new LSP();
    Memory memoryStatistic = new Memory();
    CPU cpuStatistic = new CPU();

    ExecuteRequest.RunRequest<LSP>(lspStatistic);
    ExecuteRequest.RunRequest<Memory>(memoryStatistic);
    ExecuteRequest.RunRequest<CPU>(cpuStatistic);
}

public static class ExecuteRequest {

    public static void RunRequest<TStatistic>(TStatistic statInstance) where TStatistic : Statistic {
        if(statInstance != null) {
            statInstance.SomeMethod();
        } // end if
    } // end method RunRequest

} // end class ExecuteRequest
```

**Outputs:**

> This is the LSP implementation of SomeMethod.
>
> This is the Memory implementation of SomeMethod.
>
> This is the CPU implementation of SomeMethod.

As an alternative, since with the static implementation you don't need intellisense, you could omit the generic all-together like so:

```
void Main() {
    LSP lspStatistic = new LSP();
    Memory memoryStatistic = new Memory();
    CPU cpuStatistic = new CPU();

    ExecuteRequest.RunRequest(lspStatistic);
    ExecuteRequest.RunRequest(memoryStatistic);
    ExecuteRequest.RunRequest(cpuStatistic);
}

public static class ExecuteRequest {

    public static void RunRequest(Statistic statInstance){
        if(statInstance != null) {
            statInstance.SomeMethod();
        } // end if
    } // end method RunRequest

} // end class ExecuteRequest
```

Hopefully this gives you some guidance on how to move forward.